# Change ten labels' color at the same time. There must be an easier way then typing them out one by one

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

This is what I'm trying to do, change all of the labels' colors at the same time depending on what color I've chosen in the form. Is there a way to do this in an easier manner than the one I tried?

```
private void SetColor()
    {
        if (checkBoxBlue.Checked == true)
        {
            labelOrigo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelNW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelSW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelSE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            labelNE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        }

        else if (checkBoxBlack.Checked == true)
        {
            labelOrigo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelNW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelSW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelSE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            labelNE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        }

        else if (checkBoxRed.Checked == true)
        {
            labelOrigo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelNW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelSW.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelSE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            labelNE.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code works already; there is no issue other than style.  Try asking questions like this on codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here are suggestions:

1. Add the line `using System.Drawing;` to the top of your code.
2. Declare `System.Drawing.Color.Blue`, etc. To a shorter-named constant and use that
   variable instead.
3. Use an array and a loop to reduce the code written, as shown below.

---

```
// At the top of the file
using System.Drawing;
//  ...
// In your method:
// Store associations with checkboxes and their colors
// in a convenient array, making it easy to extend in
// case additional colors need to be supported
var checkBoxColors = new[] {
  new { CheckBox = checkBoxBlue, Color = Color.Blue },
  new { CheckBox = checkBoxBlack, Color = Color.Black }
  // Add more if needed
};
foreach(var check in checkBoxColors) {
  if (check.CheckBox.Checked) {
    // Rename `check.Color` to a shorter variable 
    var color = check.Color;
    labelOrigo.ForeColor = color;
    labelN.ForeColor = color;
    // ...and so on        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is. Use a for or a foreach loop. I tend to prefer the foreach loop, but I believe for may be faster:

```
foreach(Control ctl in this.Controls)
{
    if(ctl.GetType().Name=="Label")
    {
        ctl.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```